# Get the type of element that is focused

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a page with various anchors and form-elements that can be focused and I am wondering how I can get the element that is being focused on currently if something is being focused. I think one way to do it in jQuery is with `.is(:focus)`. I'm looking for either a jQuery or vanilla js solution— just something that works.

Here is what I am trying to do in psuedo-code:

```
if (something is focused){
    get the tag name of that which is currently focused and store that in a variable as a string.
}
else {
    alert("nothing is being focused on");
}
```

Also, if you could answer this question, please do:
Isn't something always focused? Meaning it is the document / body that is focused when no specific elements are or is nothing focused until done so by the code or user?

Comment: @ultranaut Thank you for pointing that out. That question had the answer I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set a list of elements you care about `focus` on, or use a wildcard selector:

```
$(function () {
    var focusedEls = [];
    $('*:visible').bind('focus', function (e) {
        focusedEls.push(e.target);
        console.log( $.unique(focusedEls) );
    });
});
```

[Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xfwy2/](http://jsfiddle.net/xfwy2/)

There are a number of ways to store the elements that were focused, I just chose an array. Also, I'm not sure if you want to keep track of the **times** each element was focused, but if you do, just ditch the [`$.unique()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.unique/) for the full list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this with jQuery, you are looking for is the jQuery `.prop()` method. `$(someElement).prop('tagName')` will return the tag name of `someElement`.

Just threw this together, as an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kZbYv/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following:

```
$('*:focus')
```